# How to display media metadata infomation in the Media Switch output?

Tags: android, android-mediasession, mediarouter, mediasession

I developed a media app with reference to UAMP, but I encountered the following problems.
The media switch output screen opened from the notification cannot display the media information being played.
But there is UAMP, not sure what I missed? Does anyone know the reason? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason myself.
Because I didn’t set MediaSession to active correctly.